# C# selenium with Chrome Driver - not able to execute multiple asynchronous requests, also puppeteer-sharp is slower than selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, puppeteer-sharp

I am developing a C# MVC application, where I have to scrape another website for internal use. Using selenium I can successfully logIn into the website, but on search page, there are several Ajax(Xhr) requests and handling them takes quite long time in my C# code as the requests are queued and execution performs one by one.

I tried to implement threading but I think selenium uses single instance to handle all requests.

It's important to contain the session, otherwise results will not be fetched.

Is there any way I can make selenium to work asynchronously for each request without losing session or creating new instances (as I'll have to load the session & redirect to previous URL and this will take even more time & will consume more memory).

I am using following code:`

```
                ChromeDriver _driver = (ChromeDriver)System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["ChromeDriver"];
                if (_driver != null)
                {
                    string lastTabURL = _driver.Url;
                                                 
                    _driver.Manage().Timeouts().AsynchronousJavaScript = System.TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeoutInSec);
                    responseText = (String)((IJavaScriptExecutor)_driver).ExecuteAsyncScript(script2);
                    Debug.WriteLine("-- Response 1 Feteched: url: " + url + ", Started: " + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));
                    
                }`
```

In this code I retrieves the Chrome driver from session & then tries to make xHttp request to get the results, but if any requests takes time then other requests wait for that time & then they get executed and so on.

**Comparing Selenium vs Puppeteersharp:**

I debugged the the code for both Seleniun (C# with Chrome Driver) and PuppeteerSharp(C#) and found that selenium took 0.4 second to fetch a URL, and for same URL PuppeteerSharp took 2.1 seconds.
But I have found many posts that mention puppeteer is much faster than selenium. I guess that puppeteer with nodeJs may be faster than in comparison to PuppeteerSharp.

I also have one more issue that when there only 3 to 4 instances of Chrome Driver using Selenium, it takes around 35 seconds to scrape all the requests of a web page, but when user instances increases, my code assigns separate instance of Chrome Driver,  it takes around 1.5 to 2 minutes for same request. **Is there any way to handle this?**

Thanks

Comment: if all you are doing is making javascript requests you may not need Selenium at all.  You might just want something like Postman.https://learning.postman.com/docs/writing-scripts/intro-to-scripts/#:~:text=The%20Postman%20Sandbox%20is%20a,is%20executed%20in%20this%20sandbox.

Comment: Did you figure this out?